# What is the granularity of the CUDA Memory Checker?

Tags: debugging, cuda

I have a kernel that works in debug builds but fails in release builds. I suspect that I'm reading or writing out of bounds, but the CUDA Memory Checker is not showing any errors. So, I did a test where I write and read out of bounds with the following kernel:

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
  int x[1];
  for (int i(0); i < 100; ++i) {
    x[i] = i;
  }
  int t(0);
  for (int i(0); i < 100; ++i) {
    t += x[i];
  }
  c[0] = t;
}
```

The CUDA Memory Checker did not catch the out of bounds writes and reads. I was able to get an out of bounds write to be detected by increasing the loop to 1,000,000 rounds, which caused the kernel to pause at i = 502,586 (2MB out of bounds).

Is this the expected granularity at which the CUDA Memory Checker works and is there anything I can do to get it to detect small out of bounds writes (on the order of a few bytes?)

Comment: Maybe the compiler is doing one of its amazing optimizations? The result is summatory of i from 0 to 100. What happens is pass 100 as a kernel parameter (unknown at compile time)?

Comment: Seemed unlikely. Tried it anyway, and it didn't change anything :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just getting tripped up in this example by optimization, as has already been suggested.

Here's my test case:

```
$ cat t1130.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void addKernel(int *c)
{
  int x[1];
  for (int i(0); i < 100; ++i) {
    x[i] = i;
#ifdef FORCE
  printf("%d ", i);
#endif
  }
  int t(0);
  for (int i(0); i < 100; ++i) {
    t += x[i];
  }
  c[0] = t;
}

int main(){

  int *d_c;
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(int));
  addKernel<<<1,1>>>(d_c);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t1130 t1130.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1130
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvcc -DFORCE -o t1130 t1130.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1130
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Invalid __local__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000168 in addKernel(int*)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x00fffd10 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x15865d]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x16ca1]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x314b3]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x27a1]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x269c]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x26b6]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x2600]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21d65]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x2489]
=========
0 1 2 3 ========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 [0x2f31b3]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x354a6]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x2605]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21d65]
=========     Host Frame:./t1130 [0x2489]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
$
```

So if we compile your code as-is, it runs without error under `cuda-memcheck`.  But if we force the compiler to generate the actual loop, then the invalid access is detected and reported.

Also explaining your comment, if we use `-G` instead of `-DFORCE` in the above case, `cuda-memcheck` will also detect and report the error, since the optimizations are disabled.